# How can i extract Trained model information from its weight files?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I had got pre-trained model weight files of a model for audio classification. How can i extract model information from that weights given (For examples no of layers used to build architecture)? This question asked in the interview. is if possible to extract model information from its weights.

Answer (score 0):

Check these two threads

- [How to read keras model weights without a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173580/how-to-read-keras-model-weights-without-a-model)
- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/91